# excel - Update multiple columns if a column from one of the worksheet is updated

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have multiple sheets and one of the columns in all of the sheet contains a same column (say "Names"). In each of the column "Names" is a corresponding "Status" column. Each "Names" column may contain same record from one or more sheets. If one of the record in "Status" column is updated, I want to get its corresponding "Names" column value, then search all of the sheets, If it also has that same "Names" record, I should be able to updates its corresponding "Status" value based on the value from the first "Status" update.

Now, I was able to search for an answer from the web that is working (see below), the problem is it only works one way. I can update a value from a sheet (say sheet1) and it will be able to update a value from one or more worksheet. But when I tried to update a value from another worksheet (not the sheet1), it returns an error `Method "Find' of object 'Range' failed`.

Sample (this should be in each worksheet, with columns, sheet names changed):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim fn2 As Range

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    Set fn2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D").Find(Target.Offset(, -11).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not fn2 Is Nothing Then
        fn2.Offset(, 13) = Target.Value
        MsgBox "A record has been updated name_tab tab"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code errors because you're trying to offset 11 columns left of column D

**edited** after OP's clarification about:

- *to-be-searched-in* sheet names to be hard coded, since no common pattern can be found to filter them amongst all other worksheets
- `Names` and `Status` columns having, correspondingly, "Names" and "Status" headers in row 1 of every *to-be-searched-in* worksheet

**edited2** to take account of the first update row index (see lines with "****")

put this code in `ThisWorkbook` code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Const STATUSHEADER As String = "Status"
Const NAMESHEADER As String = "Names"


Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nameValue As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim sheetNames As Variant
    Dim firstUpdatedRowIndex As Long '<--| this will store first updated row index  ****

    If Not Proceed(Target) Then Exit Sub

    sheetNames = Array("Sheet0001", "Sheet0002", "Sheet0003") '<--| fill array with sheets-to-be-searched names

    On Error GoTo EXITSUB
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    nameValue = GetNameValue(Target) '<--| get value in the "Names" column corresponding row
    For Each sht In Worksheets(sheetNames) '<--| loop through to-be-searched-in sheets
        If sht.name <> Sh.name Then UpdateSheet sht, nameValue, Target.value, firstUpdatedRowIndex   '****
    Next sht

EXITSUB:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Sub UpdateSheet(sht As Worksheet, nameValue As String, statusValue As Variant, firstUpdatedRowIndex As Long) '****
    Dim namesCol As Long, statusCol As Long
    Dim f As Range

    With sht '<--| refer to current to-be-searched-in sheet
        With .Rows(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| refer to its 1st row non blank cells range
            namesCol = FindFirstCell(NAMESHEADER, .Cells).Column '<--| get its "Names" column index
            statusCol = FindFirstCell(STATUSHEADER, .Cells).Column '<--| get its "Status" column index
        End With
        Set f = FindFirstCell(nameValue, .Columns(namesCol).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)) '<--| search its "names" column for the "name" value corresponding to the changed "Status" in the originally changed sheet
        If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if any matching cell found in "Names" column ...
            .Cells(f.row, statusCol) = statusValue '<--| update its corresponding "Status" column value
            MsgBox "record in row " & f.row & " has been updated in " & .name & " tab"
            If firstUpdatedRowIndex = 0 Then firstUpdatedRowIndex = f.row '<--| store first updated row  ****
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Function FindFirstCell(value As String, rng As Range) As Range
    Set FindFirstCell = rng.Find(what:=value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=True)
End Function


Function GetNameValue(Target As Range) As String
    With Target.Parent
        GetNameValue = .Cells(Target.row, FindFirstCell(NAMESHEADER, .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, Target.Column - 1))).Column).value '<--|  search columns preceeding the 'Target' (i.e.: "Status") one for the "Names" column and get its value at the row corresponding to changed "Status" one
    End With
End Function


Function Proceed(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Proceed = rng.Cells.Count = 1 '<--| proceed if only one changed cell
    If Proceed Then Proceed = rng.Offset(-rng.row + 1) = STATUSHEADER '<--| proceed only if the changed cell is a "Status" column
End Function
```

Comment: the problem is for each sheet, the column for "Names" and "Status" varies.

Comment: and also, not all sheets should be searched. there are some sheets on the workbook that is not should be part of the search.

Comment: So which is the pattern of "Status" and "Names" columns positions across worksheets? And how to detect worksheets where to search?

Comment: @ErinSantos, could please answer my question and let me help you out? Should columns be found by means of their _header_ value (i.e. "Names" column in any sheet is the one whose _header_ in row 1  is "Names"), then the code can be easily adjusted and you don't need to hardcode anything in it but those columns header names (e.g: "Names" and "Status")

Comment: There is only a handful of worksheet to search so sheet name is where I would base my search, as for the columns, their positions are just random. `Names` and `Status` was just randomly inserted. `Names` column always comes first before `Status` column though.

Comment: "Sheet name is where I would base my search": what does that mean? "Names" and "Status" was just randomly inserted": so a "Names" column header in one sheet differs from that of any other one?

Comment: The `Names` and `Status` column header are constant but their column in their worksheet differs. For sheet1, `Names` column could be in A and `Status` column could be in C, while for sheet2, `Names` column could be in C while `Status` column could be in F. For worksheets, I do not need to search all sheets on the workbook, I just need to search a number of specificly named worksheets.

Comment: So what are "Names" and "Status" columns actual constant headers? And which row are they in? Do sheets to be searched in share a unique and common pattern (e.g.: they and only they all have names beginning with/ending with/containing "xyz", they and only they all have "wxy" in their cell "A1",...)?

Comment: They are in first row since they are header names. Their header names are `Names` and `Status`. The sheets don't really have a common pattern.

Comment: Are to-be-searched in sheets the only ones with both "Names" and "Status" headers in row 1? While as for _"They are in first row since they are header names."_: well, hang around a little bit here and you'll see things that you'd never think possible...

Comment: No, some of the sheets that do not need to be searched also have both `Names` and `Status` columns.

Comment: @ErinSantos: you may want to see my edited code which reduces both hard coding needs and (possibly, in the _refactored_ edition) debugging-maintenance efforts

Comment: I tried your code and it's working perfectly and faster. Thanks!

Comment: If I have another column that I need to populate. I want to put the content of the `MsgBox` to a `Notes` column, do I have to modify the functions too?

Comment: Apologies. Don't mind my last question. I was able accomplish it by adding a few lines. How do I reference the original sheet where the first update happened? THanks again!

Comment: Excellent answer. +1

Comment: can you tell where is the line where you reference the first updated row?

Comment: cell updating takes place in `.Cells(f.row, statusCol) = statusValue ` (right before the `MsgBox` statement in `Sub UpdateSheet()`: is that what you need?

Comment: thanks @ThomasInzina. Yours was fine as well and suitable in case there were no "Status-Names columns" searching pattern. You could leave it for useful reference

Comment: It worked but I really force it.  I immediately defaulted to a dictionary because we're looking in multiple list.  When in actuality it didn't make much sense because we are looking for a single match in each list.

Comment: I want to know how I can reference the row where a matched has been found from a specific sheet. For example if there is a match in sheet1, I want to get the row number where a match is found. Thanks!

Comment: @user3598756 apologies. I wasn't clear. What I wanted is to check this specific sheet. Let's call it master_sheet. So whenever an update happened in master_sheet, be it by user input or automated AND there is a same record from other sheet, I want to get the row where there is a match from specifically master_sheet because beside this `Status` column from `master_SHeet` is a `notes` column where I'd like to place the texts form `msgbox`. But if there is change that does not involve the `master_sheet` then, nothing will happen in `master_sheet`.

Comment: well since an user input can be involved that you'd go with a worksheet event handler. there are a lot of SO answers about such an issue: you can check and should you get stuck then back with a new post (as per SO rules: one issue= one post) with your code

Comment: if you don't help with already available SO Q&A on the same issue, yes. But be sure to post your code attempt to increase feedbacks probability